# App Engine Modeling Issue - Storing generated ID as number or string?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Say I have an blog app, with blog posts and comments.

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty()
  description = ndb.TextProperty()
```

I have another model for when user comments on a blog post:

```
class Comment(ndb.Model):
  username = ndb.StringProperty()
  blog_id = ndb.StringProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I query for all the comments for a particular BlogPost, I do:

```
query = Comment.query(Comment.blog_id==blog_id).order(-Comment.created)
```

Is this OK? My question is specifically if it is OK to store the blog_id as a string property rather than the original integer ID? I did this because it is an iOS app, and the long integer ID's was causing an integer overflow error in my iOS client.

Would this type of query scale no problem?

Comment: An entity id is only 16 digits long.  How is that a problem for an iOS app?

Comment: Not sure but I do recall some type of memory/integer overflow error. Would it make a difference though? Will it be OK to store the id's as strings?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see happening there is `Comment.blog_id` being a string and `blog_id` being a number, so you would be comparing a string with an int.
If `blog_id` is a string, then you are safe.
The way ndb/Datastore indexes works, your query will be the same with strings or integers (performance wise).